# Where should I start reading to learn how to build a good Rails gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, bundler

I'm feeling fairly seasoned in Ruby on Rails by now, and have attempted to build my own Rails plugins. Going through that process, however, I realized that I really have not found very many good resources that clearly spell out what the conventions are for creating Rails gems/plugins, and how to efficiently accomplish some of the things that I wanted to do with my plugin.

It seems to me that the documentation for buildings Rails gems is not very good, but maybe I'm not looking in the right places. In an attempt to gain insight into how other gems are built, I've read through some of the source code of the Devise plugin for user authentication. I have found virtually nothing describing a procedure similar to how Devise injects its own methods into an existing model, even though this seems like it may be a very useful thing for a lot of good gems to do.

My question is this: Where should I go to learn how to build good Rails gems? Are there spelled out conventions for how to do certain things?

Comment: anybody answer that helpful to you then accept that answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The currently popular method to do what you are trying to achieve is to use ***Engines***. Engines basically let you mount one application inside another, allowing you to do anything from add a method or two, to adding a complete blog. The [official guides](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html) have a very nice step-by-step guide to getting started, and there are many good [unofficial guides](https://www.google.com/search?q=rails%20engines), as well. An engine basically consists of a little bit of initialization code, the application code, and a dummy application for testing and development. It might look intimidating, at first, but it's much easier than it sounds, at first. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

Here is the most modern approach to gem crafting with Bundler:

```
bundle gem your_gem
cd your_gem
```

edit your_gem.gemspec and add description, summary and optional website.
Add required gems such as rspec to the Gemfile.

```
rspec --init
touch spec/your_gem_spec.rb
```

Write good tests.
Add your code to lib/your_gem.rb.
When you're finished its time to build and push to rubygems.org:

```
gem build your_gem.gemspec
gem push your_gem-0.0.1.gem
```

And thats it. Next time you make a change be sure to change the version number in version.rb.

Answer (score 0):

see below link that will help you how to build a good rails gem

[Making a Gem](http://railscasts.com/episodes/135-making-a-gem)

Comment: This is a great start. However, I'm looking for more in-depth guides on more complex gem functionality.

Comment: Realistically, for anything beyond an intermediate level there aren't a lot of tutorials - you're probably going to have to stick with your current method of busting open gems that do what you are interested in, and peeking inside...